# (UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification) Is not being called until the cocos2d frame interval goes from 15 down to 1?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, xcode4.5, nsnotificationcenter, nsnotifications

I am trying to display UIAlert view when my application gets opened from running in the background, but the notification is not getting called until the cocos2d frame interval has dropped from 15 down to 1. I don't understand what this means. Could someone enlighten me. When closing the app it shows this in the debugger.

`-[CCDirectorDisplayLink startAnimation] : cocos2d: Frame interval: 15`

Then when I reopen the app it shows the same thing.

```
-[CCDirectorDisplayLink startAnimation] : cocos2d: Frame interval: 15
```

but after about 1 or 2 seconds then I get this message `

`-[CCDirectorDisplayLink startAnimation] : cocos2d: Frame interval: 1`

in the debugger and then it calls the notification?

Comment: I think frame interval goes down because director gets paused. Find out what causes the pause, set a breakpoint to directors pause method.

Comment: Why does the frame interval have to drop to 1 before the notification is called?